# On Øksendal's Lemma 3.5

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In Øksendal's text, *Stochastic Differential Equations*, there is a statement of the Ito Isometry for functions $\phi(t,\omega)$ which are bounded and elementary.  This is Lemma 3.5 (p. 19).

**Naive Question:** Where is *boundedness*  used in his proof?

By request, here is the statement of the lemma:

**Lemma 3.5:** If $\phi(t,\omega)$ is bounded and elementary, then
$$
E[(\int_S^T \phi(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega))^2] = E[\int_S^T \phi(t,\omega)^2 dt]\, .
$$

Comment: My copy of the book is in the car (no, I'm not going to get it). Can you state the Lemma in full for those that do not have the book?

Comment: Is it merely that to ensure that the right side of the Ito isometry is finite, one wants to assume that $\phi$ is bounded?

Comment: It may have to do with some integrability bits - i.e., if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, then $f$ is a.e. bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this issue would be with the right hand side of the isometry.

However as far as I can tell however this assumption does not seem to be necessary, since according to Oksendal

> A function $\phi \in \nu$ is *elementary* if it has the form 
>   $$\phi(t,\omega)= \sum_j e_j(\omega) \chi_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}(t).$$

The redundancy comes from the fact that, to be an element in $\nu$ we must have 
$$E\bigg[\int \limits_S^T \phi(t,\omega)^2 \mathop{dt}\bigg]<\infty.$$
If we take $\Delta t_j=(t_{j+1}-t_j)$ we see that (just as in the proof of Lemma 3.5)
$$E\bigg[\int \limits_S^T \phi(t,\omega)^2 \mathop{dt}\bigg] =\sum_j \Delta t_j \int_\Omega e_j^2 \mathop{d\omega} $$

So for each $j$,we have $\int_\Omega e_j^2 \mathop{d\omega}< \infty $.

So each $e_j$ is a.e bounded, and so is $\phi$.